# Getting the DefaultSelectedItems for a form combo box field from a lookup of another SharePoint List

Tags: powerapps

I have a PowerApps form in edit mode. The source for the form is RI_Tracker. For five fields I need to populate the DefaultSelectedItems with lookup values from another sharepoint list named Program_Funded_Lookup.

Basically, when the user selects a Funded_Program code, the five fields lookup this Funded Program code and populate the DefaultSelectedItems with a field in the same row (like a Vlookup).

Here is a snippett example.

[image: PowerApp form Field]

When the user selects the Funded Program code from the combo box the 'CSU/CSU' DefaultSelectedItems should show the 'CSU/CSU' value from the Funded_program_Lookup SharePoint List.

I have tried many different functions including:

LookUp(Funded_Program_Lookup,Funded_Program = FundedProgramValue.Selected.Value,'CSC/CSU')

Using this I get an Expected Table error. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: What is the formula used in `items` property of 'CSU/CSU' drop down? You have to adjust your formula in `DefaultSelectedItems` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the syntax:

```
LookUp(Funded_Program_Lookup, Funded_Program = FundedProgramValue.Selected.Value).'CSC/CSU'
```